# Can I have single ID for Mobile & Web Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Can I have single ID for Mobile & Web Analytics?

When I checked on the Google Analytic's site, they have two different fields for Mobile & Web Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

You could technically speaking use the same web property Id for both a web and a mobile analytics account.  This would be a very bad idea. Web analytics accounts display things like pageViews and page names, while mobile analytics accounts display things like screenviews and screen names.

There would be no way to analyze them because the website only supports displaying one or the other.  That and you would be analyising two things that are not related to one another.

I recommend you create two separate web properties one for the web account and the other for the mobile account.

Comment: oh and technically speaking I think if you insert mobile data into a web account you could probably see it using the Analytics API, not sure how accurate it would be.

Comment: Actually there was an article on the Google Blog about analyzing web and app data in a single view: http://analytics.blogspot.de/2014/04/understanding-multi-device-user.html.  The idea seems to be to have one view specifically to analyte multi-device behaviour and then filtered views per data source. I have yet to meet somebody who put this successfully into practice.

Comment: @EikePierstorff yeah I tried that a while back it didn't work well.  Theres issues with not being able to see the mobile dimensions and metrics on a web account.   they aren't listed.